# Using Wirt's Leg as a weapon

Tags: diablo-ii

**If I place runes in the sockets of Wirt's Leg, can I still use it to get to the secret cow level? Or does it have to be "clean" for that to work?**

Reason I am asking is because it is the only weapon that I have with 3 empty sockets, and I have (luckily!) 3 Tal Runes. These do +75 poison damage over 5 seconds. So I would get a minimum 225 poison damage before my other perks kick in.

Comment: If anyone's curious, runewords will **not** work with Wirt's Leg.

Comment: @QAzer do you have proof they don't work? I have all 3 inserted and they are working just as designed.

Comment: [This](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/images/e/e4/Wirts-leg-IthElEth.jpg) 3-socketed Writ's Leg should have the [Malice](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Malice) runeword, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wirt's Leg is Wirt's Leg.  It still fulfills the item requirements as such.

However, it will be consumed in the process to get to the cow level, which sort of defeats the purpose of using it as a weapon.

So, yes.  It will still do it's job, but you'll be out a weapon.

Answer (score 2):

If you legitimately want to use Wirt's Leg as a weapon, you could certainly do so. Tal runes aren't overly rare, so you could put those in it. If you're concerned about losing your weapon when you want to access the cow level, fear not, because you could simply get another Wirt's leg. However, chances are good that you will have replaced the weapon by the time you are ready for the cow level anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can you it as a weapon, but it will get destroyed when you try to go to the cow level.
I'd just wait if I were you. Socketable weapons aren't that rare.